# Joining 3 tables together and selecting the null elements without using is not null

Tags: sql-server, query, null

```
select Name from Passagerare 
left join EB
on Passagerare.Personnr = EB.Personnr
left join MM 
on Passagerare.Personnr = MM.Personnr

where  Passagerare.Personnr = EB.Personnr or Passagerare.Personnr = MM.Personnr
```

[image: her is an image of the tables]

I am trying to show all the `passagerare` name that dont have any membership with `EB` or `MM` now I solved this problem with `is not null` but I was told there are other ways to solve the problem so how would I do it ? The code before gives me all the members with `EB` or `MM`

Result of code above:

[image: Result of code above]

Comment: Who told you there are other ways to solve the problem and did they happen to explain what they were or why they were better? What exactly did they say is wrong with `IS NOT NULL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way to do this is with EXCEPT. What this does is returns everything in the top statement that is not in the bottom statement. INTERSECT will return only those that match.

BOL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Example:

```
SELECT 
Personnr
FROM 
Passagerare 


EXCEPT 


SELECT 
Personnr
FROM 
EB

UNION 

SELECT 
Personnr
FROM 
MM
```